# Vagrant Up - Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant

I'm having issues with my Vagrant after installing upgrading ruby and rails using Rbenv. Now my vagrant is no longer working. Here is my results from and trying to initialize with `vagrant up`

```
    Progress: 90%/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:288:in `initialize': Permission denied @rb_sysopen - /vagrants/public-records/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id (Errno::EACCES)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:288:in `open'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:288:in `open'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:288:in `id='
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:60:in `import'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

I also tried running `sudo chmod -R 1777 tmp/` but got the same results.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what you are doing and what issues you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a lot of problems with vagrant, I think is a good tool but still had many bugs. Every time I had problems with 
`vagrant up`
I just restart my computer.